# Accessing Performance schema tables with performance schema disabled for MySQL-5.7

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to access the performance schema tables like "replication_connection_status" etc. if the performance schema is disabled for the MySQL-5.7 server? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: use : > SHOW SLAVE STATUS; to see all Values from the replication

Comment: I want to access "replication_connection_status" etc. replication related tables, as theses tables are now containing the values which earlier mysql variables like "slave_running" was conataining..so I wanted to knonw, that can I access these tables and get the information, even when the performance schema is disabled for the MySQL server?

Comment: From MySQL-5.7.2, slave running information is stored in the performance schema replication table "replication_connection_status" instead of "show slave status" query. The table "replication_connection_status" is enabled by default when you turn on the Performance schema, and the column "service_state" gives this slave running information like on, off or connecting. You should have performance schema enabled in order to access the tables.